# MYSQL declaring variables

Tags: mysql

I don't get what is wrong with this script

```
BEGIN
DECLARE crs INT DEFAULT 0;

WHILE crs < 10 DO
INSERT INTO `continent`(`name`) VALUES ('cont'+crs)
SET crs = crs + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
```

I want it to insert 10 values into the table continent but there is an error at the second line.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

MySQL does not support the execution of anonymous blocks of stored procedure code.

You need to create a stored procedure including that code and then invoke it.

Also, you were missing the semi-colon at the end of your insert statements. I fixed that. You also probably want to use concat() instead of + to generate the names, but I'll leave that change to you.

Create the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_ten_rows $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_ten_rows () 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE crs INT DEFAULT 0;

        WHILE crs < 10 DO
            INSERT INTO `continent`(`name`) VALUES ('cont'+crs);
            SET crs = crs + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Invoke the procedure:

```
CALL insert_ten_rows();
```

Answer (score 37):

declare variable in MySQL with **`@`** and assign with **`:=`**

```
SET @crs = 0; // declaration
--here your query
@crs := @crs+1 // assignment
```

*References*

- [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)
- [assignment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html)

Comment: `BEGIN
DECLARE crs INT;
SET @crs = 0;
WHILE crs < 10 DO
INSERT INTO \`continent\`(\`name\`) VALUES ('cont'+@crs)
SET @crs = crs + 1;
END WHILE;
END; ` it's not working this way either

Comment: the error i get says that: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @crs INT'

Comment: -1 because session variables are something else than block scoped variables that the questioner wants. Anyway, anonymous blocks don't work with MySQL :(