# Unknown system variable using DECLARE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL Query.

```
DECLARE RecCount Int Default 0;
SET RecCount=(select count(*) from tables where WaiterID=1 and date(TDate)=date(now()));
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'RecCount'
```

So, I googled 'declaring variables in MySQL.' It appears that everyone uses `DECLARE`:

- [First Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505522/mysql-declaring-variables)
- [Second Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505522/mysql-declaring-variables)
- [Third Result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-local-variable.html)
- [Fourth Result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html)
- [Fifth Result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

I don't understand why my query doesn't execute.

I'm using MYSQL WORKBENCH 6.0 CE and I eventually want to execute this query in PHP.

**EDIT:**
I have used the default as 0. If I remove the default 0, AND change the query to what I've written below, it executes. But it still doesn't save the result like it should!

```
SET RecCount=(select count(*) from tables where WaiterID=1 and date(TDate)=date(now()));
SELECT RecCount;
```

Comment: i have used the default as 0. and just without the default 0

Comment: You have to run that in a procedure or function.

Comment: cant you just declare variables in a script like in mssql

Comment: no you can't do that.

Comment: you want to post it as an answer then i can mark it as answered

Comment: You should have googled the error instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You have to run that code in a procedure or function.

If you use control statements you have to use them in a function or procedure.

> MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html)

Answer (score 3):

The [manual page for `DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-local-variable.html) you found says:

> This statement declares local variables **within stored programs**.

If you use `DECLARE` somewhere else you get a syntax error:

> mysql> DECLARE RecCount Int Default 0;
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the r ight syntax to use near 'DECLARE
>   RecCount Int Default 0' at line 1

*Your [first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505522/mysql-declaring-variables) clearly defines a `BEGIN...END` code block, which doesn't work (thus the question) because MySQL doesn't support anonymous code blocks.*

It's possible that your MySQL client is not configured to abort on errors and you're only getting the last one.

I have the impression that you're after session variables but you don't use `DECLARE` for that: [you use `SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html):

```
mysql> SET @foo='bar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @foo;
+------+
| @foo |
+------+
| bar  |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```