# MySQL increase value and select result

Tags: mysql, sql, increment

Is there a way in MySQL to increase a value of some row field by some increment and select the result in one statement? The emphasis is on "in one statement".

It should work something like Redis's [INCRBY command](http://redis.io/commands/incrby), where you increment a key by some increment and receive back the result, all in one operation.

For example, can I do this in one statement:

> UPDATE `table` SET `counter` = `counter` + 1 WHERE `id` = id LIMIT 1;
>
> SELECT `counter` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = id LIMIT 1;

If there is no way to do it in one statement, what would be the best way to do this performance wise?

Comment: Negatory there big fella.

Comment: "cell" is not a MySQL concept.  Can you try to rephrase the question in terms of tables and queries?

Comment: Does a stored routine call count as one statement?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, only statements pls.

Comment: MySQL would need to have a `RETURNING` clause similar to Oracle's, but it doesn't. Even if you manage to store it into a session variable, you'd need a separate call to read back the variable. Whatever your use case is, you'll possibly need to do it some other way. In any case, let's wait and see what answers come through.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: actually what would be needed is the `returning` clause as it is available in Postgres: `update foo set counter = counter + 1 where id = 5 returning id, counter` will generate a result set just like a `select` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oh, funny alternative. In Oracle you'd get `id` and `counter` as output parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL you need to create a stored procedure including that code and then invoke it.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateWithCounter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE updateWithCounter () 
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt  INT DEFAULT 0;

WHILE cnt < 10 DO
UPDATE table SET counter = cnt WHERE id = id LIMIT 1;
SET cnt = cnt  + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
CALL updateWithCounter ();
```

More on using variables in MySQL you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505522/mysql-declaring-variables)