# Migrating from Oracle to MySQL. VARCHAR2 length defined using bytes. How to port?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, migration

I have variable in Oracle procedure declared  like this:

```
myMsg  VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
```

How can I port it to mysql? Because this when I try to declare it in MySQL procedure:

```
DECLARE myMsg VARCHAR(256 BYTE);
```

MySQL throws me syntax error.

---

How can I port that Oracle variable definition to MySQL?

---

It is `256 BYTE` part that doesn't let me to declare variable in MySQL and I need to find something similar to this `256 BYTE` expression in MySQL.

Comment: Could you try DECLARE myMsg VARCHAR(256); ?

Comment: Yes, but will that mean the same?

Comment: I only know that VARCHAR(256) creates a variable for 256 characters (edited from comment belove), I'm not sure how to declare variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql, varchar colums get declared like this

```
   colname VARCHAR(256),
   another VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
```

etcetera. The Oracle syntax is different.

In stored code in MySql, inside function or procedure scope, variables get declared like this:

```
    DECLARE myMsg VARCHAR(256);
```

If you're not aware of this, you soon will be: Oracle PL/SQL and MySql's little language for stored code are very different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of `varchar` in `mysql` is `255` before `mysql 5.0.3`

From `MySql` Doc:

> A variable-length string. M represents the maximum column length in
>   characters. In MySQL 5.0, the range of M is 0 to 255 before MySQL
>   5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in MySQL 5.0.3 and later

In `MySQL 5.0.3 and later`, a `CHAR` length greater than `255` is illegal and fails with an error

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE c1 (col1 INT, col2 CHAR(500));
ERROR 1074 (42000): Column length too big for column 'col' (max = 255);
**use BLOB or TEXT instead**
```

In the error its clearly mention that `use BLOB or TEXT`

For more info about `string data type` [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is not related to my question. And also, I'm using MysQL 5.0.3+

Comment: please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505522/mysql-declaring-variables)

Comment: that variable declaration is inside the declared procedure. I just ommited this part, so that it would be easier to read. The question is really about how can I declare variable, like it was declare in oracle using this "256 BYTE" statement. I'm curious what does this statement mean. To my mind it declare varchar, which is 256 bytes long. So how can I do the same in MySQL?

Comment: i don't think `mysql` support `anonymous code block/anonymous procedure` like `oracle plsql`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a `VARBINARY(256)` in MySQL.