# mysql declaration of variable causing syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran into the following error after running this snippet of code. Thanks in advance.

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN

DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE p1 INT DEFAULT 12;

REPEAT SET x = x + 1; UNTIL x > p1 END REPEAT;

END//

DELIMITER;
```

Produces syntax error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for > the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE x int default 0;

Comment: Is this a stored routine (procedure, function, etc.)?.

Comment: This is not a procedure or a function .I wrote this code in a notepad and saved it as new.sql  and tried to run from cmd using command source.

Comment: See [13.6.3 DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) and [13.6.5.6 REPEAT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repeat.html).

Comment: I have already gone through those documentation,But for me, everything seems to be correct. i really don't have any clue!.Thanks

Comment: Code has to be in a stored program. Be aware that if you using a tutorial from another sql you may encounter many things which will not work in mysql.

Comment: should all codes in mysql be inside function or stored procedure?

Comment: No. It depends on the statements you use.

Comment: I was able to run the same code in sqlplus without any error but in mysql it is not working without procedure creation.

Comment: BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, which can appear within stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html

Comment: Is it possible to have a loop in MYSQL without creating a stored procedure?

Comment: No a loop has to be in a stored program, also declared variables have to be in stored programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL declaring variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505522/mysql-declaring-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE `x` INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE `p1` INT DEFAULT 12;
  REPEAT
    SET `x` := `x` + 1;
  UNTIL `x` > `p1` END REPEAT;
  SELECT `x`;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL `sp_test`;
```

Comment: But I am trying to run that code without use of procedure.